# Average life expectancy..exponential function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Let
$$N_0 = \text{initial number of AIDS patients}$$
$$N= \text{number of patients left}$$

The equation is given by: $$N=N_0\exp(-kt)$$
What is the average life expectancy of one person?
(The answer is $t= \frac1k$)

How did we get to this answer without using expected value and probably/statistics analysis? (differential equations problem)
Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I know how to come up with the answer using expected value, but the problem is presented as a differential equations one.

Comment: Hint. Do you know the integral that computes the expected value of a continuous distribution? And please format with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hello.. i know how to come up with the answer using expected value, but the problem is presented as a differential equations one. I am asking for a friend currently taking a DE course.. sorry about mathjax but i cannot format using my phone.

Comment: Thank you Karn for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *not very rigorous* since, as you know, the DE itself is derived using expectation and average out everything but I think you will get the overall idea.

---

Let $N(\tau)=N_0-n$, $N(\tau+\delta)=N_0-(n+1)$.
Hence, one life has lapsed in time $\delta$.

$$\tau=\frac{1}{k}\ln\frac{N_0}{N_0-n}$$
$$\tau+\delta=\frac{1}{k}\ln\frac{N_0}{N_0-(n+1)}$$

$$\delta=\frac{1}{k}\left(\ln\frac{N_0}{N_0-(n+1)}-\ln\frac{N_0}{N_0-n}\right)=\frac{1}{k}\left(\ln\frac{N_0-n}{N_0-(n+1)}\right)$$

Since this must hold true for all $n>1$,

$$\text{life expectancy}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\delta=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\ln\frac{N_0-n}{N_0-(n+1)}\right)=\frac1k$$

Comment: Thank you very much Karn. I understand the error was in presenting the problem as a differential equations one, as it really is more than that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @J.Moriarty You are welcome :) I just edited the answer to be more rigorous now please check the edited ver out.

Comment: Yep this is better. Thank you!